# Avoid flicker effect on menu buttons at screen resize

Tags: css, flexbox

I made a menu with flexbox. There is a pseudo ":after" attached to last list item, that will occupy the remaining space, unless this remaining space is below a certain percentage of the screen size. It works, but when I resize the screen, there is a flicker effect on the menu items.

```
<ul class="tags boldcond">
 <li><a href="#">Long Category Name</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mobile &amp; IOT</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Automation</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Agile</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Analysis</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Architecture</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Artificial intelligence</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Digital &amp;AI</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Diana Test</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Long Category Name</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Software Engineering</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mobile &amp; IOT</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Automation</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Agile</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Analysis</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Architecture</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Artificial intelligence asdf</a></li>
```

script.js

```
function SetLiWidth() {
  let width = window.getComputedStyle(
   document.querySelector('ul'), ':after'
  ).width;

  let percentage = Math.round(window.innerWidth) * 50 / 100;  
  let selectList = document.querySelector('ul');

  if (Math.round(parseInt(width)) < percentage) {
    selectList.classList.add('expanded');
  }else{
    selectList.classList.remove('expanded');
  };
}


window.onresize = function(event) {
  SetLiWidth();
};
```

style.css

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
    background:#64666d;
    padding:10px;
    flex:1 0 auto;
    margin:5px
}

a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none
}
ul::after {
  content:'';
  flex-grow:100;

}
ul.expanded::after {
display: none;
}
```

When I apply display:none on ul.expanded::after, I would like for the transition to be smoother? Anyone could help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At times it get width as 'auto'

Just add following line of code after you get width:

```
if(width == 'auto') return;
```

Following is the changed function:

```
function SetLiWidth() {
  let width = window.getComputedStyle(
   document.querySelector('ul'), ':after'
  ).width;
  if(width == 'auto') return;

  let percentage = Math.round(window.innerWidth) * 50 / 100;  
  let selectList = document.querySelector('ul');

  if (Math.round(parseInt(width)) < percentage) {
    selectList.classList.add('expanded');
  }else{
    selectList.classList.remove('expanded');
  };
}
```